# Repeating pattern using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of words:

> word dark king glow we end hello bye low wing

I need to find words where last letter of first word matches first letter of following word (example: `worD Dark`).

I wrote a regex expression:

```
\b\w*(\w)\W\1\w*\b
```

Currently it successfully finds 2 words in a row (`Regex.Matches[0].Value = "word dark" ; Regex.Matches[1].Value = "king glow"` etc.)

I need a regex expression which would read it as a pattern (`Regex.Matches[0].Value = "word dark king glow we end" ; Regex.Matches[1].Value = "low wing"`).

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the last word character, check inside a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if [it](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) matches the first character of the next word, put all into a [group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) for repetition and if the condition succeeded, match following word.

```
(?i)(?:\b\w*(\w) +(?=\1))+\w+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Bw24sT/1)

Used with *caseless* [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` for captured `a` matching `A` in the following word.

- if you expect *non word characters* besides space, [use negated upper `\W` instead](https://regex101.com/r/Bw24sT/2)
- for even digits and underscores between, [use `[a-z]` instead of `\w`](https://regex101.com/r/Bw24sT/3) and [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- if working with [unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category), [use `\p{L}` for letter and negated upper `\P{L}`](https://regex101.com/r/Bw24sT/4) for *non letter*

Comment: Still can't wrap my head around how it works. But hey, on the other hand, at least it works ^^

Comment: @GytisDokšas The lookahead is not consuming anything. Just think of the pattern without the `(?= +\1)` it would basically just be `(?:\b\w+ )+\w+`. But we capture the last letter in the first word and only continue if the condition succeeds that the first letter of the next word matches.

Comment: Additional question: how could I implement punctuation marks between words (e.g. `word, day` or
`word!day` (with/or without whitespaces))

Comment: @GytisDokšas As you did  with `\W+` instead of the space ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kPmCCV/5)) or anything else you consider *non word characters*.

Comment: Tried with \W+ myself, didn't work ar first, retried after your suggestion and now it does work, dang, Regex is some voodoo magic ^^

Answer (score 3):

For the record here a very expressive non regex version. I does't require picture ;)

```
static IEnumerable<(string W1, string W2)> GetPairs1(string input)
{
    var words = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (!words.Any()) yield break;

    for( int i = 1; i < words.Length; i++) 
        if(words[i][0] == words[i-1][words[i-1].Length-1]) 
            yield return (words[i-1], words[i]);
}
```

## Test

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var input = "word dark king glow we end hello bye low wing";

    foreach (var p in GetPairs1(input)) 
        Console.WriteLine($"{p.W1} {p.W2}");
}
```

### Output

```
word dark
dark king
king glow
glow we
we end
low wing
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question and there is [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58895791/6553328) here.

#### With Positive Lookahead

I guess,

```
(?is)\w*(\w)(?= (\1)\w*)
```

might be somewhat closer, there might be edge cases though, for which you'd probably want to look into the positive lookahead here in this block:

```
(?= (\1)\w*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xfJ5pL/1/)

---

#### With Positive Lookbehind

You can also lookbehind, and capture things, if/as you wish and code, maybe with some expression similar to:

```
(?is)(?<=([a-z])\s)(\1)([a-z]*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OtF84D/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?is)\w*(\w)(?= (\1)\w*)";
        string input = @"word dark king glow we end hello bye low wing
word Dark King Glow We End hello bye LoW wing";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xfJ5pL/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/xfJ5pL/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

[image]

---

### Complexity

Lookarounds in general are not really complexity-friendly methods, yet I can't think of a better way now.

Comment: It's closer but still not quite what I'm looking for. Let's say I need to find the longest (as in word count) combination using this pattern in a bigger text. With some more functions it would be possible to make it with your expression but it would be much simpler if there was a way to get it as whole values (currently it creates many `Regex.Matches` and increases complexity)